# Debug a DLL loaded by a 3rd party executable

Tags: c#, debugging, dll

I have a built application which loads plugin dlls written in .Net.

I'm trying to figure out how to debug my dll from visual studio while it has been loaded by the 3rd party.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you simply put a breakpoint in the relevant function in the DLL, and then launch the application in the debugger (or attach to it while it's running)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two ways to to this:

1. In project properties of your DLL project , in the the Debug tab, 
   choose "start external program" as the the start action. So when
   debugging your DLL, VS will start the 3rd party exe
2. In VS, at the "tools" menu, choose "attache the process" to attach to 3rd exe

Comment: Ah cool. I didn't know you could just attached to the process and it would automatically find the dll within.

Comment: As of July 23, 2022, for Visual Studio 2022, you will want to follow [this guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2022#specify-a-calling-app-in-a-c-dll-project-net-core-net-5). A lot of things have changed since 2014.